# GPS accuracy is too high and geolocate point (blue dot) is jumping around in IOS-Safari after one of the updates in IOS 14 version?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a web application that is built with mapbox-gl-js. The gps accuracy is jumping between 5m to 65m sometimes as high as 620m in IOS-Safari. Sometimes it stays at 65m for a long time. I also hear a lot of complaints from users that geolocate point (blue dot) is jumping around. These issues didn't exist 4-5 months ago. They cannot be reproduced in Android-Chrome. I built a POC app to get the bottom of these issues and having the same issues in this app     https://laughing-sinoussi-270dac.netlify.app/. Any recommendation is appreciated!

App.js

```
// TO MAKE THE MAP APPEAR YOU MUST
// ADD YOUR ACCESS TOKEN FROM
// https://account.mapbox.com
mapboxgl.accessToken =
  "ACCESS_TOKEN";
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: "map", // container id
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
  center: [-96, 37.8], // starting position
  zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});
let geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
  positionOptions: {
    enableHighAccuracy: true
  },
  trackUserLocation: true,
  fitBoundsOptions: {
    maxZoom: 20
  }
});
map.addControl(geolocate);

geolocate.on("geolocate", e => {
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML =
    // e.point is the x, y coordinates of the mousemove event relative
    // to the top-left corner of the map
    JSON.stringify("accuracy: " + e.coords.accuracy + " m") +
    "<br />" +
    JSON.stringify("latitude: " + e.coords.latitude) +
    "   " +
    JSON.stringify("longitute: " + e.coords.longitude);
  //   + '<br />' +
  //   JSON.stringify("longitude:"e.coords.longitude);
  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with Mapbox.

Comment: I can second the OP's findings. iOS has been jumping to a point where it's not usable anymore. dejavu, did you ever find a solution?